# El subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto junto con el condicional perfecto en una oración simple

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, condicional

Del libro "El arte de no amargarse la vida" (España):

*"Sari le entregó el dinero, el maestro se lo guardó en el bolsillo y dijo: —Sé que **habrías acudido** a Benarés y **te hubieses lavado** en el Ganges."*

Ya sé que en el tercer condicional (solo el ejemplo) se puede estar el subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto tanto con otro subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto como con el condicional perfecto (de https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/si-clauses-third-conditional/). Y el significado sería el mismo en ambos casos.

Pero, ¿por qué en esta concreta oración se usaron ambos tiempos verbales y no solo uno de ellos? Esta oración no es el tercer condicional con dos cláusulas.

P.S. Les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en caso de que haya algunos.

Comment: No me era familiar la expresión "tercer condicional" para este tipo de oración. No parece ser un término técnico estándar. Es bueno que nos hayas provisto de una referencia.

Comment: @pablodf76 yo creo que se suele hablar de *primer, segundo, tercer* condicional por analogía con *first, second, third* conditional en inglés, ya que siguen una estructura muy similar. No creo que *primer, segundo, tercer* condicional sean términos estándar en la gramática española. Por otro lado, son términos muy útiles para explicar el concepto a hablantes no nativos...

Comment: @pablodf76 En esta cadena https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35336/23475 ya escribí el comentario "de hecho, nunca observaba el primer, el segundo y el tercer condicional como la terminología estandar en español. Es verdad. Los utilizaba solo para comprender el tema del uso del condicional en español."

Comment: @wimi Estoy de acuerdo. Y por eso los utilizaba en comprender - "ya que siguen una estructura muy similar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En efecto, en esta oración no hay un patrón de lo que llamas "tercer condicional" completo. Sólo está el resultado; la condición está implícita ("**Si no hubieses hecho otra cosa,** (entonces) sé que habrías acudido a Benarés...").

Como ya sabes, en el parte del resultado de la proposición condicional se puede usar tanto el subjuntivo como el condicional. Dado que ambos son lo mismo, quien escribió ese texto decidió usar primero uno y después el otro, quizá para variar. El uso de dos tiempos perfectos seguidos en una oración puede sonar cacofónico.

Creo que en este caso suena y se ve muy extraño usar primero el condicional y después el subjuntivo, cuando el sujeto de ambos verbos es el mismo y se encuentran tan cercanos. Yo hubiera (o hubiese, o habría) usado en ambos casos el mismo tiempo/modo verbal. En cualquier caso, es una cuestión de gustos.