# El subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto con el condicional simple

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, condicional

De la serie de Netflix "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

"*Si yo no le hubiera dicho que fuera ahora **estaría** vivo.*"

Tambíen del  video de BBC Mundo "Bolsonaro positivo por coronavirus: "Estoy perfectamente bien"
" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu-srgsjjtE (al principio):

*"Como mucha gente, si no me **hubiera hecho** el examen, no **sabría** el resultado y resultó positivo."*

Me parece que esto es el caso del condicional mixto. Querría comprobar si he entendido correctamente.

El condicional simple se usa en ambos ejemplos porque se refiere a la situación "ahora". Si se usara el condicional perfecto en lugar del condicional simple, eso se refiría completamente a un periodo en el pasado:

*"Si yo no le **hubiera dicho** que **fuera** ahora **habría estado** vivo."* [podría estar vivo en aquel tiempo en el pasado, pero ahora - no o sí. Además, supongo que en este caso, ¿no se puede usar la palabra "*ahora*" con "*habría estado*"?]

*"Como mucha gente, si no me **hubiera hecho** el examen, no **habría sabido** el resultado y resultó positivo."* [en este caso no habría sabido el resultado en aquel tiemplo en el pasado cuando le hicieron una prueba y no se refiere al periodo cuando habla.]

He entendido correctamente?

P.S. Como siempre, les agradezco a todos ustedes que corrijan errores si hay algunos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé a qué te refieres con "condicional mixto". En ambos casos hay oraciones del mismo tipo muy común: *"si [condición] (entonces) [consecuencia]"*. Los nombres de los modos verbales son confusos. la *condición* no va normalmente en condicional sino en subjuntivo; lo que va en condicional es la *consecuencia*.

Tal como imaginaste, en ambos casos se utiliza el condicional simple en la consecuencia porque se está hablando desde el punto de vista del presente. En la primera oración esto es explícito porque se usa la palabra "ahora".

> "Si yo no le hubiera dicho que fuera ahora estaría vivo."

Esto significa: "Ahora estaría vivo (deducimos que está muerto) si en el pasado yo no le hubiera dicho que fuera." No es posible utilizar el condicional compuesto en esta oración si hay una palabra "ahora". Gramaticalmente es posible hacerlo si no hay un "ahora", pero el resultado no tiene sentido. Puedo imaginar un ejemplo similar donde tenga sentido:

> "Si yo no le hubiera indicado el camino, **se habría perdido** en la ciudad."

En un caso como el de mi ejemplo inventado, ambas cosas pertenecen al pasado: la condición y la consecuencia hipotética. "Se habría perdido en la ciudad" significa que (en caso de cumplirse la condición) el sujeto ya estaría perdido en el momento en que yo pronuncio la oración. De hecho podría continuar la historia con un condicional en presente:

> "Si yo no le hubiera indicado el camino, se habría perdido en la ciudad **y ahora estaría intentando** ponerse en contacto conmigo para volver a casa."

Espero estar comprendiendo cuál es tu propósito al preguntar. Hasta aquí estos usos de verbos en español son prácticamente paralelos a los que se encuentran en inglés, con la excepción (obviamente) de que en inglés no se usa el subjuntivo.

Comment: Sobre el tema del condicional mixto, encontre en esta cadena https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21349/23475 lo que fue dicho por Gustavson: ""Si fuera rico, no me hubiera ido a Australia." En este punto disiento con Pablo. Creo que estamos frente a una condicional mixta, donde la condición se refiere al presente (una hipotética situación actual) y el resultado se refiere al pasado (una hipotética situación anterior)." Después encontré esta página en inglés sobre el condicional mixto en inglés https://www.colanguage.com/es/el-tercer-condicional-y-el-condicional-mixto

Comment: Pero, de hecho, nunca observaba el primer, el segundo y el tercer condicional como la terminología estandar en español. Es verdad. Los utilizaba solo para comprender el tema del uso del condicional en español.

Comment: sobre lo que tú dijiste en "la condición no va normalmente en condicional sino en subjuntivo; lo que va en condicional es la consecuencia.", en Hispanoteca (http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Condicional%20hipot%C3%A9tico.htm) yo encontré "El condicional perfecto.....Se emplea en la apódosis de las oraciones condicionales, pero nunca en la prótasis". Esto es solo para confirmar.